# Why ReadFile function writes garbage to buffer?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, file-io, readfile

Let's say I decided to open an existing file with the `CreateFile` function. The content of the file is `Hello world`. There is also a buffer (char array with size 11 and filled with zero bytes) that should contain the contents of the file.

And when I try to read the file with the `ReadFile` function, certain garbage is written to the buffer. The debugger (I've tried GDB and LLDB) says that the contents of the buffer after reading is `\377?H\000e\000l\000l\000o\000\000w\000o\000r\000l\000d\000\r\000\n\000\r\000 \n, '\000'`, and in a human-readable form, it looks like this  `■ H`.

I've tried not filling the buffer with zeros. I tried to write (with `WriteFile`) to a file first, then read. I also tried to change the value of how many bytes to read with `ReadFile`. But it still doesn't change anything.

Also, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Code:

```c
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    HANDLE file = CreateFile("./test_file.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
                             NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        puts("Failed to open");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t length = strlen("Hello world"); /* 11 */
    char buffer[12];
    DWORD count = 0; /* Is always 11 (length of "Hello world") after reading */

    memset(buffer, '\0', length + 1);

    if (!ReadFile(file, buffer, (DWORD) length, &count, NULL)) {
        puts("Failed to read or EOF reached.");

        CloseHandle(file);

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("buffer: '%s'\n", buffer);
    printf("count: %lu\n", count);

    CloseHandle(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the console, the output of the program looks like this:

```
buffer: ' ■ H'
count: 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text file itself is not written in a 7bit [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or 8bit [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) byte encoding, like you are expecting. It is actually written in a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) byte encoding, with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the front of the file (bytes `0xFF 0xFE` for UTF-16LE).  You are simply reading the file's raw bytes and displaying them as-is without any regard to their encoding.

Comment: Thank! Something was really wrong with the encoding. For some reason, the file encoding was UCS-2 BE BOM.

Comment: @eax-ebx your file is in an LE (little endian) encoding, not a BE (big endian) encoding.  But yes, UCS-2 is the predecessor of UTF-16, so characters in the ASCII range will be encoded using the same bytes in both UCS-2 and UTF-16.